# Facebook open source project FBCTF not starting after installation?

Tags: linux, facebook, ubuntu, ssl, open-source

> What is FBCTF? link here [Github Link](https://github.com/facebook/fbctf)
>
> The Facebook CTF is a platform to host Jeopardy and “King of the Hill”
>   style Capture the Flag competitions.

I have followed the instructions like here
Production

> ```
> The target system needs to be Ubuntu 14.04. Run the following commands:
> sudo apt-get install git
> git clone https://github.com/facebook/fbctf
> cd fbctf
> ./extra/provision.sh prod `pwd`
> This will place the code in the /var/www/fbctf directory, install all dependencies, and start the server. Be ready to provide the path for your SSL certificate's CSR and key files.
> ```

`` sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/facebook/fbctf
cd fbctf
./extra/provision.sh prod `pwd` ``

and after the final code is executed it asked me for where to install ssl certificates and ssl_keys ,so i have created a ssl empty folder in the project folder and i executed the command again.Which gave me an error like this

````
root@sai:/home/ubuntu/fbctf# ./extra/provision.sh prod `pwd`
[+] Provisioning in prod mode
[+] Creating code folder /var/www/fbctf
[+] Copying all CTF code to destination folder
chmod: cannot access ‘/etc/update-motd.d/51-cloudguest’: No such file or directory
[+] language-pack-en is already installed. skipping.
[+] emacs is already installed. skipping.
[+] Adding osquery repository keys
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.aGSiJeuAvn --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/webupd8team-sublime-text-3.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 1484120AC4E9F8A1A577AEEE97A80C63C9D8B80B
gpg: requesting key C9D8B80B from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key C9D8B80B: "osquery (osquery) <osquery@fb.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
[+] Adding MyCLI repository keys
OK
[+] apt-transport-https is already installed. skipping.
deb https://packagecloud.io/amjith/mycli/ubuntu/ trusty main
[+] Adding HHVM key
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.pkVxhp2x4w --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/webupd8team-sublime-text-3.gpg --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0x5a16e7281be7a449
gpg: requesting key 1BE7A449 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 1BE7A449: "Paul Tarjan <pt@fb.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
[+] Adding HHVM repo
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease [65.9 kB]
2% [Waiting for headers] [1 InRelease 1,086 B/65.9 kB 2%] [Waiting for he                                                                         Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
                                                                         Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease
21% [Waiting for headers] [1 InRelease 13.7 kB/65.9 kB 21%] [Waiting for                                                                          Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
                                                                         Hit http://dl.hhvm.com trusty InRelease
                                                                         21% 
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
[+] osquery is already installed. skipping.
[+] mycli is already installed. skipping.
[+] memcached is already installed. skipping.
[+] htop is already installed. skipping.
[+] Installing MySQL
[+] mysql-server is already installed. skipping.
[+] git is already installed. skipping.
[+] hhvm is already installed. skipping.
[+] Copying HHVM configuration
; php options

pid = /var/run/hhvm/pid

; hhvm specific

hhvm.jit = true
hhvm.enable_xhp = true
hhvm.force_hh = true
hhvm.server.port = 9000
hhvm.server.type = fastcgi
hhvm.server.default_document = index.php
hhvm.server.upload.upload_max_file_size = 25M
hhvm.log.level = Error
hhvm.log.use_log_file = true
hhvm.log.file = /var/log/hhvm/error.log
hhvm.log.header = true
hhvm.log.access[default][file] = /var/log/hhvm/access.log
hhvm.log.access[default][format] = "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b"
hhvm.server.source_root = /var/www/fbctf/
hhvm.repo.central.path = /tmp/hhvm.hhbc
hhvm.mysql.socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
hhvm.pdo_mysql.socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
hhvm.mysqli.socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[+] HHVM as PHP systemwide
[+] Enabling HHVM to start by default
 System start/stop links for /etc/init.d/hhvm already exist.
[+] Restart HHVM
 * Restarting HHVM FastCGI Daemon hhvm                                      [ OK ] 
[+] Installing composer
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading 1.1.0...

Composer successfully installed to: /var/www/fbctf/composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar
Running composer as root/super user is highly discouraged as packages, plugins and scripts cannot always be trusted
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
Running composer as root/super user is highly discouraged as packages, plugins and scripts cannot always be trusted
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
[+] npm is already installed. skipping.
[+] nodejs-legacy is already installed. skipping.

/usr/local/bin/flow -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/flow-bin/cli.js

> flow-bin@0.24.2 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/flow-bin
> node lib/install.js

  ✔ flow binary test passed successfully
flow-bin@0.24.2 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/flow-bin
├── logalot@2.1.0 (figures@1.6.0, squeak@1.3.0)
└── bin-wrapper@3.0.2 (lazy-req@1.1.0, os-filter-obj@1.0.3, each-async@1.1.1, bin-version-check@2.1.0, bin-check@2.0.0, download@4.4.3)
Running "force:eslint" (force) task

Running "force-internal:pre:eslint" (force-internal) task
>> Enable force mode for task eslint.

Running "eslint:dist" (eslint) task

/var/www/fbctf/src/static/js/plugins.js
  51:9  error  Move function declaration to function body root  no-inner-declarations

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

Warning: Task "eslint:dist" failed. Used --force, continuing.

Running "force-internal:post:eslint" (force-internal) task
>> Reset force mode for task eslint.

Running "run:flow" (run) task
No errors!

Running "browserify:dist" (browserify) task
>> Bundle src/static/build/app-browserify.js created.

Running "copy:browserify" (copy) task
Copied 1 file

Running "sass:dist" (sass) task

Done, but with warnings.
[+] nginx is already installed. skipping.
[+] Deploying certificates
 -> SSL Certificate file location? /ssl
 -> SSL Key Certificate file location? /ssl
cp: cannot stat ‘/ssl’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/ssl’: No such file or directory
Generating DH parameters, 2048 bit long safe prime, generator 2
This is going to take a long time
................................+.........................+.........................................+..........................................................................................................................................................................+............+................................+.............................................+..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................+......................................................+....................................+..............................................................................................+............................................+......................................................................+..............................++*++*
# Do not send nginx version number in error pages or server header
server_tokens off;

add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com; font-src 'self'; frame-src 'self'; object-src 'none'";

server {
  listen 80;
  rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
  listen 443;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/fbctf.csr;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/fbctf.key;

  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';

  ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/certs/dhparam.pem;

  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;
  resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
  resolver_timeout 5s;

  add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
  add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";

  add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store";
  add_header Pragma "no-cache";
  expires -1;

  root /var/www/fbctf/src;
  index index.php;
  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
  error_page 400 401 402 403 404 500 /error.php;
  client_max_body_size 25M;
}
rm: cannot remove ‘/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default’: No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/fbctf.conf’: File exists
nginx: [emerg] BIO_new_file("/etc/nginx/certs/fbctf.csr") failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/nginx/certs/fbctf.csr','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
 * Restarting nginx nginx                                                   [fail] 
[+] Installing Unison 2.48.3
[+] Remember install the same version of unison (2.48.3) in your host machine
[+] Creating DB - fbctf
ERROR 1007 (HY000) at line 1: Can't create database 'fbctf'; database exists
[+] Importing schema...
[+] Importing countries...
[+] Importing logos...
[+] Creating user...
ERROR 1396 (HY000) at line 1: Operation CREATE USER failed for 'ctf'@'localhost'
[+] DB Connection file
[+] Adding default admin user
[+] The password for admin is: 73d8adba7b2fe3f64e2f8300aa248a8f
[+] fbctf deployment is complete! Ready in https://10.10.10.5
```
````

Can anyone know how to fix the issues and also if anyone used this before might be helpful

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the certificate file is missing - your nginx config says:

```
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/fbctf.csr;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/fbctf.key;
```

check if those two files exist.

If they do not exist - just create them:

```
cd /etc/nginx/certs
openssl genrsa -des3 -out self-ssl.key 2048
openssl req -new -key self-ssl.key -out self-ssl.csr
cp -v self-ssl.{key,original}
openssl rsa -in self-ssl.original -out self-ssl.key
rm -v self-ssl.original
openssl x509 -req -days 4000 -in self-ssl.csr -signkey self-ssl.key -out self-ssl.crt
mv self-ssl.crt fbctf.csr
mv self-ssl.key fbctf.key
```

then restart your nginx server:

```
service nginx restart
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to try another method, maybe you could try running with docker. I wrote some instructions [here](https://github.com/qazbnm456/dockerized_fbctf). You can run under both dev and prod mode. With running under prod mode, I use Let's Encrypt to generate certs for you, so you don't have to worry about that.

To your question, the provision script doesn't ask you where to install certs, it's asking you the location where the certs you generated located, see [here](https://github.com/facebook/fbctf/blob/master/extra/lib.sh#L85-L92). Thus, you need generate your certs and tell script where they are.

Comment: Finally thanks for help and it worked !! @Lobsiinvok

Answer (score 1):

Try using `./extra/provision.sh dev 'pwd'`

It solved the problem for me tho^^ the script will automatically deal with the SSL certificates

Comment: `[+] Provisioning in dev mode
[+] Creating code folder /var/www/fbctf
[+] Copying all CTF code to destination folder
rsync: change_dir "/home/ubuntu/fbctf//pwd" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1183) [sender=3.1.0]
[+] Setting permissions
chmod: cannot access ‘/etc/update-motd.d/51-cloudguest’: No such file or directory`

Comment: Manually copy all the files under /fbctf to /var/www/fbctf

Comment: I cant copy because there was some permission problem

Comment: Have you installed it in your system,Is it working fine?

Comment: My SSL certificate install worked fine. I just need to install the composer. Try sudo cp

Comment: `ubuntu@sai:~$ ls
API_Projects
apt-get_packagees.txt
Cryptography
fbctf
geoedge.py
hacker-scripts
Mastering Python - Networking and Security - Working Files
Python_WebScraping
theHarvester
ubuntu@sai:~$ sudo cp fbctf /var/www/
cp: omitting directory ‘fbctf’
`

Comment: sudo cp -r ./fbctf/* /var/www/fbctf/